# Swift SKStoreReviewController error

Tags: swift, api, crash, instance, review

I implemented the new SKStoreReviewController in my app by using
SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()

The problem is sometimes after hitting the "Not Now" button in the review controller I get the crash below..

```
[SKRemoteReviewViewController release]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

I know it has to do with SKStoreReviewController but I don't know how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: Also seeing this error, it's got to be a bug in Apple's framework. Happens even if calling it from the main thread. Going to stay away from that review controller until it is polished up a bit.